# Include helper class in view

Tags: yii2, helper, autoload

I am working on a requirement of where I have to include all common methods like pagination, etc. which were used in my views into all my views. For this purpose I thought helper file is useful and created helper file in `common\helpers\` directory with name `Common` as helper file name. I am facing difficulty in using this helper file in my view file.

I have included this helper file in my view as

```
use common\helpers\Common;
```

When I open the page **I am getting error as "Class 'common\helpers\Common' not found"**

My helper file: Common.php

```
namespace common\helpers;
class Common
{
  protected $_file;
  protected $_data = array();

  public function __construct($file)
  {
    $this->_file = $file;
  }
  public static function getCommonHtml($id=NULL)
  {
   ----
   ----
  }
  -----
  --- Some other methods---
  -----
}
```

I googled for this & got few solutions but they never worked.

Comment: Did you have any other class in `common` namespace? Did they work?

Comment: No, this is my first helper class which I created

Comment: Can be common a reserved word?

Comment: Could it be that you folder is named 'helper'? Had this issue a couple of times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your new namespace in your `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "common\\": "common/"
    }
},
```

And the run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

---

Alternatively you could declare alias for new namespace, so Yii autoloader  will handle it (like in [advanced template](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/44dd561109a0377d25b64511e50b5ca8494dac1d/common/config/bootstrap.php)):

```
Yii::setAlias('@common', dirname(__DIR__))
```

But Yii autoloader will be dropped in Yii 2.1, so I would stick to composer-way (or do both - alias may be useful not only for autoloading).

Comment: I tried your solution, I have added your code to my composer.json & ran the command `composer dump-autoload` but It was showing exception as `"[Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException] "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON Parse error on Line 80"`

Comment: You have a syntax error in your `composer.json`. You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate its content. BTW: make sure that you remove these three dots from json - this is only example how to add this to existing autoloading rules.